# I tried to find the biggest of four int . with C. But the program is not working

Tags: c

Different types of answers are coming. Sometimes the code is working. Sometimes not. I cannot find the solution.

```
#include<stdio.h>

 int max_of_four (int a, int b, int c,int d)
   {
    
    if(a>b)
    { 
      if(a>c)
      {
        if(a>d)
        {
          printf("%d",a);
          }
          else
          { 
          printf ("%d", d);
          }
      }
    }
    else if (b>c)
    {
         if (b>d)
         {
            printf ("%d", b);
         }
         else 
         printf ("%d", d);
    }
    else if (c>d)
    {
        printf("%d", c);
    }
    else("%d",d);
    return a, b,c,d;
   }


 int main (void)
    {
      
      int a, b, c, d;
      
      scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
      
      int ans = max_of_four(a, b, c, d);
      
      printf("%d", and);
    
      return 0;
   }
```

Comment: What happens when 2 of the variables are equal?  I think therein may be the issue.

Comment: `return a, b,c,d;` Whats this?

Comment: How about making a function returning `max` of two numbers only? Then use it as `max(max(a,b), max(c,d))`. Surely will look much cleaner, maybe unnoticeably less performant.

Comment: `return a, b, c, d;` is basically the same as `return d;` (assuming none are declared with the `volatile` qualifier).

Comment: `printf("%d", and);` should be `printf("%d", ans);`

Comment: How should i try.. the max_of_four giving me right answer individualy

Comment: You could use a variable: `int m = a;` `if (m < b) m = b;` `if (m < c) m = c;` `if (m < d) m = d;` `return m;`.

Comment: Sometimes a good place to begin when troubleshooting a complicated problem is to break the complications down to their component pieces, and look at them one at a time.  When you look at your overall code base, and you cannot identify any component pieces, then consider simplifying your algorithm...

Answer (score 1):

Yous need a variable for storing the maximum value. When you find the biggest number you just put it in the variable for the maximum.

```
if(a>b) { 
    if(a>c) { 
        if(a>d) { 
            max = a;
...and so on...
```

Then at the end of the function you return the variable `max` and then in the `main` you print it. (You can even print the value in `max_of_four()` but then why returning a value?)

A better way would be:

```
scanf("%d", &max);

for( i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {

    scanf("%d", &n);

    if( n > max ) {
        max = n;
    }
}
```

Or you can even use an array if you need to do other stuff with the inputs

Answer (score 1):

> *"Sometimes the code is working. Sometimes not. I cannot find the solution."*

The logic in your code is difficult to follow, which make it easy to miss seeing contributions to logic errors.

To simplify the problem, this approach encapsulates the primary repeated logic into a macro, then calls it repeatedly.  (Note that a function could be used here as well with similar benefits in terms of cleaning up the code.)

```
//Note: NOT for use with incremented arguments, (eg. MAX(x++, y++))
#define MAX(x, y) (((x) > (y)) ? (x) : (y))


int max_of_four (int a, int b, int c,int d)
{   
     int max=0;
       
     max = MAX(  a, b);
     max = MAX(max, c);
     max = MAX(max, d);
    
     return max;
}
```

`printf()` statements can be added back in if OP needs to see intermediate results, but example is kept as is to highlight its simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

OP's original version of `max_of_four` does not search all possibilities. A version that does search all possibilities is as follows:

```
int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    if (a > b)
    {
        if (a > c)
        {
            if (a > d)
            {
                return a;
            }
            else
            {
                return d;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (c > d)
            {
                return c;
            }
            else
            {
                return d;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (b > c)
        {
            if (b > d)
            {
                return b;
            }
            else
            {
                return d;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (c > d)
            {
                return c;
            }
            else
            {
                return d;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The main problem with that approach is that the amount of code is proportional to 2 to the power of n-1.  It can be reduced a bit by some careful changes to the control flow to avoid repeating identical code fragments:

```
int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    if (a > b)
    {
        if (a > c)
        {
            if (a > d)
            {
                return a;
            }
            else
            {
                return d;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (b > c)
        {
            if (b > d)
            {
                return b;
            }
            else
            {
                return d;
            }
        }
    }
    if (c > d)
    {
        return c;
    }
    else
    {
        return d;
    }
}
```

The above common fragment combining technique saves some lines of code, but it is harder for the programmer to check that all possibilities have been accounted for because the code is not well "structured" (in the "structured programming" sense).

A far simpler approach is to use a variable to keep track of the largest value. The amount of code required with this approach is proportional to n:

```
int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    int m = a;
    if (m < b)
    {
        m = b;
    }
    if (m < c)
    {
        m = c;
    }
    if (m < d)
    {
        m = d;
    }
    return m;
}
```